# I can't seem to download Xcode 4.2 upgrade

Tags: xcode4, ios5

I'm running Xcode 4.1 (4B110) ad trying to upgrade to version 4.2 so I can test stuff on my iOS 5 iPhone and iPad.  Trouble is the appstore says it is installed.  Clearly it isn't.  I've got an old version of 3.2.5 or something like that and this 4.1 version.

Anyone got any ideas.  I just spoke to someone at Apple developer hotline who said:

"It might be a problem, I don't know.  I can't even get to your details because we have no systems... Try again on Monday!"

So a nice quiet weekend for me unless anyone can help.

Ta.

Rob.

UPDATE:
Suddenly the appstore told me I had one update available... for Xcode 4.2

So now it's almost finished downloading (1.8G) for the second time and still nothing installed.

All installed fine once the download actually happened and downloaded twice for some reason (I think it did that last time as well).

Comment: Once you Xcode4.2 update finishes (via the App Store) you will still need to locate in your Applications folder the "Install Xcode" app and run it to actually install Xcode4.2. Yeah, it's a dumb process.

Comment: This is what i already told him!

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the comments guys.  I know how to install it.  I just could't figure out why the app store was telling me it was already installed about two hours before it allowed me to download the new installer was all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your application folder, you will find Xcode installer, run this and you will be fine!

Edit: I think it is called "Install xCode"

Comment: Well yes, but after your update in the app store, you have to install Xcode via the installer again, what i said.

Comment: Wesso, thanks.  But the problem wasn't how to install it... it was how to update from 4.1 so i 'could' install it (more specifically if it was a known issue). Anyway all good now.

Answer (score 1):

My further problem was that I already had "Install Xcode.app" (version 4.1.1) in my Applications folder, which prevented me from downloading the version 4.2 from Mac App Store. I deleted my existing Install Xcode.app, then I was able to download Install Xcode.app (ver 4.2), then I was able to update to Xcode 4.2